# View's pivot of universal animation overlay not working

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm currently trying to make a universal method for an animation overlay. Works this way: pass activity as a parameter -> method attaches required views onto Activity's rootview, invalidates it and starts in this case rotate animation. However the animation's pivot doesn't apply to view correctly, everything works except that, so it just rotates from View's X and Y, which is incorrect.

The method:

```
fun createLoading(activity: Activity, activityWidth: Int): Animation {
    val loadingAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.animation_loading_rotate)

    val parent = activity.window.decorView.findViewById<ViewGroup>(android.R.id.content)

    val loadingBg = ImageView(activity)

    loadingBg.tag = "customLoadingBg"
    loadingBg.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    loadingBg.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    loadingBg.setImageResource(R.drawable.darken_background)

    val loadingImage = ImageView(activity)

    loadingImage.tag = "customLoadingImage"
    loadingImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_web)
    loadingImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    loadingImage.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)       //TODO pivot doesn't work. Again...
    loadingImage.layoutParams.width = (activityWidth * 0.1).toInt()
    loadingImage.layoutParams.height = (activityWidth * 0.1).toInt()
    loadingImage.pivotX = (activityWidth * 0.05).toFloat()
    loadingImage.pivotY = (activityWidth * 0.05).toFloat()

    loadingImage.x = ((activityWidth / 2 - (activityWidth * 0.1 / 2).toInt()).toFloat())
    loadingImage.y = 0f

    parent.addView(loadingBg)
    parent.addView(loadingImage)

    loadingAnimation!!.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
            parent.removeView(parent.findViewWithTag<ImageView>("customLoadingImage"))
            parent.removeView(parent.findViewWithTag<FrameLayout>("customLoadingBg"))
        }

        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
            loadingBg.alpha = 0.5f
            loadingImage.pivotX = (activityWidth * 0.05).toFloat()
            loadingImage.pivotY = (activityWidth * 0.05).toFloat()
            Log.d("loadingimg_pivotX", loadingImage.pivotX.toString())
            loadingBg.bringToFront()
            loadingImage.bringToFront()
        }
    })

    loadingImage.post {
        activity.runOnUiThread {
            parent.invalidate()
            parent.getChildAt(parent.childCount - 1).startAnimation(loadingAnimation)
        }
    }

    return loadingAnimation
}
```

As you can see I even tried to put it into the animation's onAnimationStart method, but doesn't work.
I even tried using a predefined XML animation and applying to the view, but neither of those worked out for me.
Appreciate any ideas.

EDIT:
Declaration of the R.anim.animation_loading_rotate

```
android:duration="750"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="360"
```

Comment: The " parent.getChildAt(parent.childCount - 1)" is also just me looking for some workaround, calling the View results the same.

Comment: Do you set any pivot in `animation_loading_rotate` for rotate animation?
What is your desired result? Do you have any pictures of it? Or similar this in other apps?

Comment: @aminography Yes, I'm using it in other parts of the app and it works fine, however those are being drawn as activity starts (it's hardcoded in the layout's XML). This is unfortunately behaving way differently than I expected it to be.

Comment: @JakubKostka Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be nice to have sample, to check it locally. I'm not sure, about which pivot you are talking about in this sample. Pivot in our case, should be **relative to the View under animation**, not parent. So in our case, if it's rotation, the right changes would be next.

```
loadingImage.pivotX = (loadingImage.getWidth() * 0.5).toFloat()
loadingImage.pivotY = (loadingImage.getHeight() * 0.5).toFloat()
```

Last note, I strongly recommend to stick with Android `Property Animation` not `View Animation`. You can simply replace your sample with `ObjectAnimator`, and probably you issue could be resolved. Because `ObjectAnimator` not just animate but navigates View changes, where simple View animation just redrawing object. Check more detail [from the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation).

Comment: The only downside of ObjectAnimator is its start and end "transition" basically it just slows down, which results in different looking animation. But it works as I expected it to be. Please post an example of ObjectAnimator, so it follows the requirements of the bounty and so it could help others too, thanks.

Comment: For this "Slows down" on "start and end 'transition'", I suggest you using different Interpolators. They are one-liners to configure, and are very meaningful: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-interpolators-a-visual-guide

Comment: Also, keep in mind that ObjectAnimator cam be a little bit annoying if you use code ProGuard/R8. I would recommend ValueAnimator (its superclass) whenever possible.